# Transparent PNGs and a JPEG combine in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have a case where I need to combine two transparent layers on top of JPEG files.

Here a sample setup:

```
wget -O bg.jpg http://www.grahamowengallery.com/photography/Flowers/roadside-flowers.jpg
wget -O layer.png http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/6271450/640/TRANSPARENT-EMBELLISHMENTS/pink-flower-transparent-png.png
wget -O logo.png http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Imagemagick-logo.png
```

I can get desired result with commands:

```
composite bg.jpg \( -compose Overlay layer.png \) bg2.jpg
composite bg2.jpg \( -compose Overlay logo.png \) result.jpg
```

This is good, but I want to avoid writing bg2.png to drive.

I tried:

```
composite bg.jpg \( -compose Overlay layer.png \) \( -compose Overlay logo.png \) result2.jpg
```

but this results on layer.png on black background. How can I fix this?

Comment: I assume that as neither of the answers below were accepted you did what you wanted another way. Care to tell how that was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't make `composite` working, but `convert` works:

```
convert.exe bg.jpg layer.png -compose Overlay -composite logo.png -compose Overlay -composite result2.jpg
```

Further reading: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/

Answer (score 2):

I can not test this at the moment but you may be able to use layers merge and you should be able to use the URLs in your code.

```
$cmd = "http://www.grahamowengallery.com/photography/Flowers/roadside-flowers.jpg ".
" http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/6271450/640/TRANSPARENT-EMBELLISHMENTS/pink-flower-transparent-png.png ".
" http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Imagemagick-logo.png -layers merge ";
exec(" convert $cmd result.jpg ");
```

You are not using any positioning for your layers - are you going to introduce that later? If so you can add -page +0+0 in front of each image to locate them where you want. +0+0 would be changed to the location.